# Align a <div> to the top, and one to the bottom of a table

Tags: html, css

I'm having trouble with some vertical CSS positioning. I would like to create a page with the following layout:

```
B AAA
  AAA 
  AAA
C AAA
```

A is a grid (table) of data
B is aligned to the top of the grid
C is aligned to the bottom of the grid

How do I get B and C to align correctly?

EDIT: Sorry for the confusion about Div/Table tags! I'm ideally looking to do this with pure CSS, but if it's a lot of work then I'll settle for dittodhole's solution of using a table.

Comment: Two ques: 1) is each "AAA" in it's own row? 2) do you want B and C to live outside the grid, or can you place them inside the grid if necessary?

Comment: I'm looking for a solution that doesn't effect the grid (A). Instead I would like to wrap the grid in Div/Table tags.

Comment: if you don't want this to work with ie6, then you can take chris' answer ... otherwise i would be pleased :)

Answer (score 6):

I just tested this (adds in a wrapper div):

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #wrapper{ position: relative; }
            #b, #c{ position: absolute; left: 0; width: 80px; background: #ccc; }
            #a{ margin-left: 80px; }
            #b{ top: 0; }
            #c{ bottom: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="b">Contents of B</div>
            <table border="0" id="a">
                <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
            </table>
            <div id="c">
                Contents of C
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

divs C and B need to be given a fixed width, and absolutely positioned. The wrapper is given relative positioning to make this work. Table A is given a margin equal to the width of C & B.

I've not tested cross-browser, just Firefox 3.

Comment: What does? :)  Seriously, if you need it to work on IE6 you're using table layouts.

Comment: if something works with ie6 depends only on how hard you try! as the op did not specify any browser-limitations, it has to be a cross-browser-solution :)

Comment: I'll take your word for it - I don't have IE6 to test with. IE7 works though.

Comment: Also width of B is variable, so I can't give A a margin of B's width

Comment: Get IE TAb https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/1419 IE TAb add-on for Firefox (yes it runs IE instances in Firefox tabs).

Answer (score 4):

why so fishy - this is pretty easy:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: top;">B</td>
        <td rowspan="2">grid</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td style="vertical-align: bottom;">C</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: It would be pretty straightforward to do this exclusively with tables. I believe that the OP wants to do it via CSS only which is very valid methodology.

Comment: look at his comment: "instead I would like to wrap the grid in Div/Table tags."

Answer (score 1):

I wasn't able to find any solution to this problem that worked for me. The closest thing I found was a solution that only worked if you had only 1 row. I am using the ASP.NET Calendar Control and want a div at the bottom of each date cell. The solution I came up with was to have JQuery guess at the height of the biggest cell and individually set the margin-top for the bottom div to make it work. locationInfo is the  to be moved to the bottom of each cell. num_events finds the number of entries listed above in the cell.

```
var line_height = 24; // line height plus padding
$(document).ready(function () {
    // find out the most events in one day
    var most_events = 0;
    $(".locationInfo").each(function () {
        // get number of events in this cell
        var parent_td = $(this).parent();
        var num_events = parent_td.children().length - 2;
        if (num_events > most_events) {
            most_events = num_events;
        }
    });
    //alert(most_events);

    // loop through each (location info) div and reposition by setting margin-top
    // this could  be improved further by finding the most_events for each week instead of the whole month
    $(".locationInfo").each(function () {
        //$(this).css("top", 50);
        parent_td = $(this).parent();
        num_events = parent_td.children().length - 2;
        $(this).css("margin-top", (5 + (most_events * line_height)) - (num_events * line_height));
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

using some jQuery, I can get this working cross-browser (including IE6). A border is required on the wrapping div to get IE6 working (might be a hasLayout thing?). Div B can be a variable width, and everything should accomodate.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <style type="text/css" media="screen">
            #wrapper{ position: relative;  border: 1px solid #fff; }
            #b, #c{ position: absolute; left: 0; background: #ccc; margin: 0; }
        </style>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
            $(function(){
                var b_width = $('#b').width();
                var a_height = $('#a').height();
                var c_height = $('#c').height();
                var c_top = a_height - c_height;
                $('#a').css({"margin-left": b_width + "px"});
                $('#c').css({top: c_top + "px"});
            })
        </script>
    </head>

    <body id="">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <div id="b">Contents of B</div>
            <table border="0" id="a">
                <tr><th>Header</th><th>Header</th><th>Header</th></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
                <tr><td>Data</td><td>Data</td><td>Data</td></tr>
            </table>
            <div id="c">
                Contents of C
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: this won't be pure css :) but i like it! hehe

Comment: I couldn't get it entirely working as requested in IE6 without a little "help" =)

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with pure div design using this [grid layout generator](http://www.pagecolumn.com/grid_layout_generator.htm). 4 rows and 4 columns. leave the 2nd and 3rd grid of the 1st column blank.

Answer (score 0):

this is the solution:

```
    <style type="text/css">
    table { width:500px; border-collapse:collapse}
    th, td { border:1px solid black; vertical-align: top;}
    th { width:100px; }
    td { background:#ccc; }
    .wrap { position:relative; height:100%; padding-bottom:1em; background:#aaa; height:200px;}
    .manage { text-align:right; position:absolute; bottom:0; right:0; }
    p{ margin: 0 0 5px 0; }
    </style>



<table>
    <tr>
            <th>Mauris tortor nulla, sagittis ut, faucibus eu, imperdiet ut, libero.</th>
            <td><div class="wrap">
                <p><a href="http://www.pronexo.com">www.pronexo.com</a></p>
      <div class="manage">Edit | Delete</div></div></td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
            <th>Cras diam.</th>
            <td><div class="wrap"><p>Mauris tortor nulla, sagittis ut, faucibus eu, imperdiet ut, libero. Sed elementum. Praesent porta, tellus ut dictum ullamcorper, est ante condimentum metus, non molestie lorem turpis in sapien. Aenean id enim. Nullam placerat blandit ante. Aenean ac ligula.</p><div class="manage">Edit | Delete</div></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```